# In Flutter, How can I change TextFormField validation error line style?

Tags: forms, flutter, styles, textfield

I want to set a different color for the error line created by the validator in TextFormField but I don't know how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change** the **color** and the **width** to your likings providing `errorBorder` and `focusedErrorBorder` inside `InputDecoration` as decoration  for `TextFormField`:

```dart
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedErrorBorder:UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0))
          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: please conside voting and accepting the answer if it solves your problem :)